# How can I use my text field and slider input in my Lambda expression?

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently making a tip calculator and I have hit a wall. My textbook, *Big Java, Late Objects*, did not have the answer. I scoured stack overflow and a bit of Reddit too but I was only able to partially solve my dilemma. I feel as though I am on the right track. The issue lies within the lambda expression **calcTipClick** connected to the **calculateTipButton**. **EDIT** How can I use the user input from the slider, split check, and checkAmtTextField to do my calculations of the GUI. Sorry

```
public class TipCalcApp extends Application {
    // declare interface controls

    Label titleLabel, checkAmtLabel, tipPercentLabel, splitLabel, tipAmtLabel;
    Label totalLabel, amtPerPersonLabel;

    TextField checkAmtText, tipAmtText, totalText, amtPerPersonText;

    Slider tipPercentSlider;

    ChoiceBox splitChoiceBox;

    Button calcTipButton;

    // declare a grid pane (8 rows and 2 columns)
    GridPane grid;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // instantiate labels and their properties
        titleLabel = new Label("Tip Calculator");
        titleLabel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        titleLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        checkAmtLabel = new Label("Check Amount");
        checkAmtLabel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        checkAmtLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        tipPercentLabel = new Label("Tip Percent: ");
        tipPercentLabel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        tipPercentLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        splitLabel = new Label("Split");
        splitLabel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        splitLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        tipAmtLabel = new Label("Tip Amount");
        tipAmtLabel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        tipAmtLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        totalLabel = new Label("Total");
        totalLabel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        totalLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        amtPerPersonLabel = new Label("Amount Per Person");
        amtPerPersonLabel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        amtPerPersonLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

        // instantiate text fileds and their properties
        checkAmtText = new TextField();
        tipAmtText = new TextField();
        tipAmtText.setEditable(false);
        totalText = new TextField();
        totalText.setEditable(false);
        amtPerPersonText = new TextField();
        amtPerPersonText.setEditable(false);

        // instantiate a slider and its properties 
        tipPercentSlider = new Slider();
        tipPercentSlider.setPrefWidth(300);
        tipPercentSlider.setMin(0);
        tipPercentSlider.setMax(25);
        tipPercentSlider.setMajorTickUnit(5);
        tipPercentSlider.setMinorTickCount(0);
        tipPercentSlider.setBlockIncrement(5);
        tipPercentSlider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        tipPercentSlider.setShowTickMarks(true);
        tipPercentSlider.setSnapToTicks(true);
        tipPercentSlider.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        tipPercentSlider.valueProperty().addListener(
                (observable, oldvalue, newvalue) ->
                {
                    // show integer values only
                    tipPercentLabel.setText(String.format("Tip Percent: %2d%s", newvalue.intValue(), "%"));
                });

        // instantiate a choice box and its properties
        splitChoiceBox = new ChoiceBox();
        splitChoiceBox.getItems().addAll("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
        splitChoiceBox.setValue("1");

        // instantiate a button and its properties
        calcTipButton = new Button("Calculate Tip");
        calcTipButton.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        calcTipButton.setOnAction(e -> calcTipClick());

        // instantiate a grid pane and its properties
        grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(15);
        grid.setVgap(15);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        grid.add(titleLabel, 0, 0, 2, 1);
        grid.addRow(1, checkAmtLabel, checkAmtText);
        grid.addRow(2, tipPercentLabel, tipPercentSlider);
        grid.addRow(3, splitLabel, splitChoiceBox);
        grid.add(calcTipButton, 0, 4, 2, 1);
        grid.addRow(5, tipAmtLabel, tipAmtText);
        grid.addRow(6, totalLabel, totalText);
        grid.addRow(7, amtPerPersonLabel, amtPerPersonText);

        // instantiate the grid pane and put items in in grid

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid);
        scene.getRoot().setStyle("-fx-font: 15 'Comic Sans MS'");

        primaryStage.setTitle("Tip Calculator");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    private void calcTipClick() {

        //Gather choiceBox
        String choiceInput = splitChoiceBox.getValue().toString();
        int choiceSelection = Integer.parseInt(choiceInput.substring(0, 1));

        //Gather Slider information
        String sliderInput;
        sliderInput = tipPercentLabel.getValue().toString();
        int sliderSelection = Integer.parseInt(sliderInput.substring(0, 1));

        //Gather textField amount

    }
```

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you explained what the actual issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are asking, but this is an idea of how you can calculate the tip and split it in your calcTipClick() method.  You should look at formatters to ensure format, rounding, etc.  But this should give you the general idea.

```
private void calcTipClick() {

    //Gather choiceBox
    String choiceInput = splitChoiceBox.getValue().toString();
    int choiceSelection = Integer.parseInt(choiceInput.substring(0, 1));

    //Gather Slider information
    Number sliderInput = tipPercentSlider.getValue();

    //Gather textField amount
    String val = checkAmtText.getText();
    NumberStringConverter nsc = new NumberStringConverter();
    Number amount = 0;
    try {
        amount = nsc.fromString(val);
    }catch (Exception pe) {
        //Need to handle a parse error if the user isn't entering numbers
        //Should look at text formatters to ensure amount is only entered valid
        amount = 0;
    }
    Number tipAmount = amount.doubleValue() * sliderInput.doubleValue()/100;
    tipAmtText.setText(tipAmount.toString());

    Number totalAmount = tipAmount.doubleValue() + amount.doubleValue();
    totalText.setText(totalAmount.toString());

    Number perPerson = totalAmount.doubleValue() / choiceSelection;
    amtPerPersonText.setText(perPerson.toString());

}
```